# How to prime with maple syrup?

Tags: bottling, priming

I'm not necessarily looking for a flavor add from the maple, but I want to carbonate my beer with some pure Vermont maple syrup that my brother harvested and prepared.

I'm comfortable with the amount I'll use, but I'm not sure exactly how to add it to my beer.

I typically bottle prime with sucrose, which I dilute in 2 cups of boiling water, let chill and then mix into the beer in my bottling bucket.

Does the same process apply for maple syrup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking about how to add the syrup, my concern would be contaminants, not necessarily in the syrup itself, but in the bottle, and around the cap.

I would handle it just like you handle sugar - add to some water, boil and then add that to the bottling bucket. That will ensure it's sanitary. I usually prime into a bucket that's already siphoned to 1/4 full with the batch of beer, so the solution doesn't just hit the bottom, and the continued siphoning of beer into the bucket will provide a natural stirring motion which mixes it well.

Comment: Brilliant! Cheers!

Comment: Funny follow up here. I popped the first two bottles last night and both gushed empty in my hands. Only been in the bottle for two weeks too.   Oh well, all in the name of science I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to determine the fermentability of your particular maple syrup and compare it to a typical priming sugar. I've read multiple sources that claim maple syrup is anywhere from 65%-100% fermentable so really its all dependent on the maple syrup you have.

The most common number I've heard is 65% So if you believe your syrup to be 65% fermentable you will need to use 7.69oz (5/.65) of Maple syrup to get the same amount of carbonation. This is of course based on the rule of thumb calculation of 1oz per 1gal of sucrose.

If you want to follow this [Home Brew Digest](http://hbd.org/brewery/library/YPrimerMH.html) Link you should increase your priming addition by 50% for maple syrup.

**EDIT**

As far as how to add, I would dilute your syrup to pouring consistency and pasteurize the amount you are planning on using by bring it to a near boil. Then you can batch prime the entire volume of beer / bottle.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Jared,  Thanks for chiming in. As I said above, I already have the volume part down. The question is, how do I add it to the beer?

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: It's risky because of this fermentability issue. You should round up or you run the risk of the bottles exploding. But this could lead to undercarbonation. Seems like it would be nice to be able to use it, but it's ultimately impractical because of the risks, none of which exist for priming sugar (bad idea). I would save it and use it in a brew.